frontend deployment of provided url on choreo wso2 failure
In fact, i hosted my frontend and backend on choreo wso2, after building and deploying(development not production) when i tried the provided https url i got:
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
i tried to rebuild and then redeploy many time to check if is going to work but it didn't. I thought it was related to the fact that i have to wait for some time after deployment and then try but it didn't work.
i expect to see the frontend getting render as the "/" or "/register" or "/login" added to the provided url.
when i check the log there is nothing 'No logs found'
